# One big increase in after hours

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

I'm a novice and was watching Adobe (ADBE) after hours.  It closed at $570.45 and dropped in after hours on earnings news.  It then traded sort of even until just one big spike and then back down.  Help me understand why a buyer would buy at $570 when it has been trading at $514 and then falls back to $514.  Or is there some other mechanism at play?

[image]

Comment: @littleadv I think my dupe is more relevant that yours, as this looks more like a data glitch than actual volatility.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense

Comment: @nanoman Doesn't appear to be a glitch as I refresh multiple times and it's been 2 hours.  It's still there and there is a small one for TSLA today as well (only about $3).

Comment: @littleadv  Not sure if it explains it.  I understand liquidity and volatility, but that would mean the stock was trading at $514 and the only sell order was $570 and someone took it.  Mistake on their part?

Comment: Erratic prices during the pre-market and after hours can occur due to a fat fingered trade.  However, it's improbable that this was the case here ADBE is a liquid large cap stock and does not have $55 wide bid/ask spreads during after hours.  This was surely a bad data entry. To the OP, if you post the time of the price spike, I'll check Time & Sales tomorrow, assuming that you don't have access to it.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - When ADBE was trading in the $510 area, the B/A spread would have been at most, a few dollars, and likely, less than a dollar.  Probably 10,000s of shares trading after the earnings release.  A buy order for $570 would be filled at the ask price circa $510.

Comment: @AbraCadaver "_Doesn't appear to be a glitch as I refresh multiple times_" If the glitch was in the source data for whatever site you're looking at, it would persist browser refreshes.

Comment: Thanks @BobBaerker 3/14 17:37

Comment: @AbraCadaver - I looked at Time and Sales on Interactive Brokers.  Between 17:35.00 and 17:40.00 on 3/14, there were no trades anywhere near $570.  The NBBO bid was in the vicinity of $515 for that entire time period as well.